# Problem installing iOS beta app from appcenter using on xcode simulator iphone device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

A team I'm working with is developing an app using Cordova.

I've usually been testing it using physical android and iPhone devices. But now I need to test on a newer iPhone than I have access to. So I figured I try install it on a Simulated iPhone 12 on my Macbook. (I believe the iPhone simulator of Xcode?)

So I managed to register my simulated device in Appcenter.ms where I can see the app and the different versions. However when I hit the download button for the latest version. Nothing happens. There's no error but clearly, the app is not being installed or download.

Is it not possible to install external apps on the simulated devices? Is there anything I need to configure in my simulated device before apps can be installed?

Are there any other good free (or not super expensive) iPhone emulators to use instead of the one that comes with MacOS/Xcode?

Appreciate any tips that can help. Being able to test the app on a simulated device would greatly help my workflow.

[Screenshots from appcenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQpNi.jpg)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: AFAIK, the simulator is not a device . You may try to install the app by drag/drop the iPad on it, but you need to be using at least a M1 Mac . Otherwise the binary will not be compatible.